# shift() in data.table v1.9.6 is slow for many groups

Tags: r, data.table

Thanks for implementing shift in dt1.9.6 first.
When I have many different groups, `shift()` is against expectations slower than my old code:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
mg <- data.table(expand.grid(year = 2012:2016, id = 1:1000),
                 value = rnorm(5000))
microbenchmark(dt194 = mg[, l1 := c(value[-1], NA), by = .(id)],
           dt196 = mg[, l2 := shift(value, n = 1,
                               type = "lead"), by = .(id)])
## Unit: milliseconds
##   expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq        max  eval
##  dt194  4.93735  5.236034  5.718654  5.623736  5.74395   9.555922   100
##  dt196 83.92612 87.530404 91.700317 90.953947 91.43783 257.473242   100
```

A detailed script is here: https://github.com/nachti/datatable_test/blob/master/leadtest.R

Did I misapply `shift()`?

Edit: Avoiding `:=` doesn't help ([@MichaelChirico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3576984/michaelchirico)):

```
microbenchmark(dt194 = mg[, c(value[-1], NA), by = id],
               dt196 = mg[, shift(value, n = 1,
                                   type = "lead"), by = id])

## Unit: milliseconds
##   expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
##  dt194  5.161973  5.429927  5.78047  5.698263  5.798132  10.42217   100
##  dt196 79.526981 87.914502 92.18144 91.240949 91.896799 266.04031   100
```

Apart from this using `:=` is part of the task ...

Comment: I do not believe it is a reasonable expaction that `shift` can beat `c(value[-1], NA)`. There might be potential for improvement, but the base R solution here is extremely optimized and a function that offers much more versatility (e.g., non-vector input) must be slower.

Comment: [@Roland](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland): It's just slower for many groups. If there are just a few groups (e.g. 2), `shift()` is slightly faster. For an example click the link above.

Comment: I think you should take this to the data.table bug tracker.

Comment: Ok. Reported it here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1534

Comment: You shouldn't be using `` `:=` `` in your benchmarks. Just run `mg[ , c(value[-1L], NA), by = id]` and `mg[ , shift(value, 1, "lead"), id]`

Comment: [@MichaelChirico](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3576984/michaelchirico): I added your suggestion in `leadtest.R` (see above). It's not faster and the intention was to use `:=`.

Comment: Fyi, Michael's comment was just about proper benchmarking, not a suggestion for how to address your problem. Generally, each run in a benchmark should be independent, but with `:=` the table is modified so they are not. By the way, no need to include a link in each @ you do.

Comment: You are right. I usually use e.g. `mg1 <- copy(mg)` for it. But as shown that was not the problem. In which  @ I didn't include a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table` version `1.14.3` this has been resolved and `shift` becomes faster than ever.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
mg = data.table(expand.grid(year=2012:2016, id=1:1000),
                value=rnorm(5000))
microbenchmark(v1.9.4  = mg[, c(value[-1], NA), by=id],
               v1.9.6  = mg[, shift_no_opt(value, n=1, type="lead"), by=id],
               v1.14.3 = mg[, shift(value, n=1, type="lead"), by=id],
               unit="ms")
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq    max neval
#   v1.9.4  3.6600  3.8250  4.4930  4.1720  4.9490 11.700   100
#   v1.9.6 18.5400 19.1800 21.5100 20.6900 23.4200 29.040   100
#  v1.14.3  0.4826  0.5586  0.6586  0.6329  0.7348  1.318   100
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation!